# Is there a way to just kill rviz?

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please make rviz just respect ctrl-c, no questions asked. Yes, I have read
http://answers.ros.org/question/45885/rviz-unsaved-changes/

When developing URDF, and playing with Gazebo simulation, I have to kill all ROS processes including rviz all the time. I know that C/Linux programs are ALLOWED to catch and ignore certain signals, but this "design decision" (and similar for gzserver and several python friends) costs me half an hour of my life every single day.

Why can't the stupid thing just stop, when there is no reason to continue? ctrl-\ is not 100% friendy to X11 and the rest of the world. When the user types ctrl-c, the process should just terminate, no questions asked.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/81696/is-there-a-way-to-just-kill-rviz?/) by [Norman Hendrich](https://answers.ros.org/users/3046/norman-hendrich/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2013-09-20

Post score: -2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2013-09-20**:
What version are you using? In my experience, Ctrl-C works as expected with rviz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you for your comment. Since this is apparently a very emotional issue for you, I'm sure you're motivated enough to fix this and submit a pull request. I will personally review and merge it.

---

Originally posted by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) with karma: 1444 on 2013-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 12

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ctrl+C works for me. Or all processes could be killed by system monitor

---

Originally posted by [wafeeq](https://answers.ros.org/users/6400/wafeeq/) with karma: 3 on 2013-09-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can use linux command  for killing all rviz process:

```
 $ killall -9 rviz
```

---

Originally posted by [houssem trabelsi](https://answers.ros.org/users/44082/houssem-trabelsi/) with karma: 21 on 2019-08-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1